# calculate age from birthdate in java

Tags: java

```
Main.java:6: error: class BirthDate is public, should be declared in a file named BirthDate.java
public class BirthDate {
       ^
1 error

Process exited - Return Code: 1
```

The code:

```java
package birthdate;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BirthDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your birth date (yyyy-mm-dd format only) ");
        String st = sc.nextLine();
        LocalDate Dob;
        Dob = LocalDate.parse(st);
        System.out.println("Age is :- "+calcAge(Dob));
    }

    static int calcAge(LocalDate Dob)
    {
        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
        int age = Period.between(Dob,currentDate).getYears();
        return age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you the problem.

> Main.java:6: error: class BirthDate is public, should be declared in a file named BirthDate.java

Rename your file from `Main.java` to match the name of the class, `BirthDate.java`.

Comment: Alternatively, don't compile the file `Main.java` and run it as is. Refer to [Using Source-File Mode to Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#using-source-file-mode-to-launch-single-file-source-code-programs) in the JDK documentation.

Comment: @Abra - Well, yes it works.  But it is not a good idea.  It is better to have your source filename and classname matching.